# Can't delete or change specific file

Tags: java, windows, file, nio

I have one particular file that, even it's been written by my own process, can't be deleted:

```
Files.copy(source, destination, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
Files.deleteIfExists(destination);
```

No matter what I try, I always get:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\ProgramData\FAForever\bin\BsSndRpt.exe
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
```

All other files, with EXACTLY the same user/group permission and owner, don't have this problem. And no, the file isn't opened, since I just copied it there.

How can this possibly be? How could I find out? (ProcMon only gave "BUFFER OVERFLOW" but no access violation or so) How can I fix it?

Comment: Does it have to be Java or is it neglectible how the file got deleted as long as it is gone ?

Comment: Did you try procexp and its find handle function to find out who might be blocking the file ? It could be an unclosed handle or your AntiVirus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the file properties to be not as 'Read only'

Go to the file itself using: Windows Explorer -> right click -> Properties.

Change the file permissions in the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: omg it's time to sell my PC and never touch one again.. it really was the read only flag xD thank you man